# URL path matcher without regex

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a scenario where I want to match the URL against the pattern. So i have a Url like

```
/users/1 
/users/1/roles
/users/1/roles/1
```

If I give a pattern like /user/* it should match only /users/1. If i give pattern like /user/*/* it should match to only /user/1/roles. So here asterisk matches up to the next slash character only. How can I achieve this without regex?

Comment: You can achieve this by splitting both strings using `string.split("/")` and matching the string parts but regex would be simpler. An existing library even simpler. Where does the no-regex constraint come from?

Comment: Yes my patterns are stored in cache e.g redis so I can't stored compiled regex in cache engine as there are some fields in Matcher which transient so the tree which Matcher generate for regex checking not generated properly. So the other approach is I have to compile the regex every time when a call made in the application. I don't want to store the compiled regex in application memory (in memory) as patterns can be changed at any time in Redis. Performance also matter here too as path will be check everytime

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
boolean match(String path, String pattern) {
    String[] wantParts = pattern.split("/");
    String[] haveParts = path.split("/");
    if (wantParts.length != haveParts.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<wantParts.length; ++i) {
        if (!wantParts[i].equals("*") && !haveParts[i].equals(wantParts[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```